# derivation of fibonacci log(n) time sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

I was trying to derive following equation to compute the nth fibonacci number in O(log(n)) time.

```
F(2n) = (2*F(n-1) + F(n)) * F(n)
```

which i found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) form the fibonacci matrix equation stated there but i stuck in deriving it.
I understood the derivation till the

```
(-1)^n = F(n+1)*F(n-1) - F(n)^2
```

but then how do we reach from the above equation to the below equation is unclear to me.

```
F(m)*F(n) + F(m-1)*F(n-1) = F(m + n-1)
```

In the wiki page only a single line is mentioned which says

> since $A^n A^m = A^{n+m}$ for any square matrix A, the following identities
> can be derived (they are obtained form two different coefficients of
> the matrix product, and one may easily deduce the second one from the
> first one by changing n into n + 1),

please help me in understanding the derivation.

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: If the first relation you quote were true, cancellation of the factor $F(n)$ on the two sides would give $2F(n-1)+F(n)=1,$ not true of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @coffeemath just noticed my mistake. I corrected it, please have a look !

Comment: sumit-- That relation now looks OK, at least I think I've seen it somewhere. But I don't immediately know its derivation, and you already seem to have found a wiki reference to follow for it. Good luck!

Comment: BTW: If you only want to compute the Fibonacci number $F_n$ in $O(\log n)$ operations, you can forget the formulas and directly work with the matrix powers using a fast square-and-multiply powering algorithm, and use the $(2,1)$ element of 
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\1 &0
\end{pmatrix}^n,$ e.g. from 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\1 &0
\end{pmatrix}^{50} = \begin{pmatrix} 20365011074 & 12586269025\\12586269025 &7778742049
\end{pmatrix}$$
you get $F_{50}= 12586269025.$

Comment: @gammatester why should i go for the matrix approach you mentioned when i already have a faster recurrence equation. you can compare the performance if you want. anyways I am interested in the derivation of the posted equation. can you help me with that ?

Comment: I do not say you should... but note that the matrix power method is conceptually more simple to implement than your formulas, it can be used for Fibonacci polynomials $F_n(x)$ with the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}x&1\\1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$ and it is really efficient: 1 multiply, 3 squares and (in the polynomial case) if the loop bit is set another multiply. How does this compare with your implementation?

Comment: @gammatester can you just help me with the derivation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wiki reference shows that for $n>1$ you can recover  $F_n$ as the (1,1) component of 
$$A^{n-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}^{n-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}F_n & F_{n-1}\\ F_{n-1}& F_{n-2}\end{pmatrix}$$
(you also could use the other elements). Now compute the matrix product
$$\begin{pmatrix}F_n & F_{n-1}\\ F_{n-1}& F_{n-2}\end{pmatrix}
\times \begin{pmatrix}F_m & F_{m-1}\\ F_{m-1}& F_{m-2}\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}F_n F_m + F_{n-1}F_{m-1} & *\\ * & *\end{pmatrix}
=A^{n-1}A^{m-1} = A^{n+m-2} = \begin{pmatrix}F_{n+m-1} & F_{n+m-2}\\ F_{n+m-2}& F_{n+m-3}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and read-off the $(1,1)$ component to get

$$F_n F_m + F_{n-1}F_{m-1} = F_{n+m-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

A simpler explanation of [@gammamatester's fantastic answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834546/325368):

For $n>1$ you can recover  $F_n$ as the (1,0) component of 
$$A^{n}=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}^{n} =
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_{n}\\ F_{n}& F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$

We know that $$A^{N} * A^{M} = A^{N+M}$$ that is by multiplying the matrices of $n^{th}$ and $m^{th}$ fibonacci numbers, we'll get the matrix of $(n+m)^{th}$ fibonacci.

Now putting $n$ =$m$ :
 $$A^{N} * A^{N} = A^{2N}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_{n}\\ F_{n}& F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
\times \begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_{n}\\ F_{n}& F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}^2 + F_{n}^2 & F_{n}(F_{n+1}+ F_{n-1})\\ F_{n}(F_{n+1}+ F_{n-1}) & F_{n}^2 + F_{n-1}^2\end{pmatrix} = A^{2n} = \begin{pmatrix}F_{2n+1} & F_{2n}\\ F_{2n}& F_{2n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

For even indices, compare $(0,1)$ entry:

$$F_{2n} = F_{n}(F_{n+1}+ F_{n-1})$$

For odd indices, compare $(0,0)$ entry:

$$F_{2n+1} = F_{n+1}^2 + F_{n}^2$$