# Fibonacci Sequence Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

I was given the following to prove and I have not a clue as to how to approach this problem. I have a solid understanding or Complete Induction and Mathematical Induction but I couldn't quite grasp Structural Induction. I have a test soon and I would really appreciate if anyone could explain how to solve problems of the sort.

Prove that $$f_{k}f_{n}+f_{k+1}f_{n+1}=f_{n+k+1}$$

where $f_{k}$ is the k_th Fibonacci number.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834546/61216 for a proof (with obvious shifts for the indices) using the 
[matrix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)
of the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @gammatester That's a little above what I'm at right now but thanks for the input I'll make sure to bookmark it for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction on $\;k+n\;$: for $\;k+n=1,\,2\;$ (whatever you choose or both of them) the claim is trivially verified. Assume for all indexes up to $\;k+n\;$ and prove for $\;k+n+1\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}&\text{First Case}\,: k+1\;:\;\;\;f_{k+1}f_n+f_{k+2}f_{n+1}\stackrel?=f_{n+k+2}\end{align*}$$

but then

$$f_{k+1}f_n+f_{k+2}f_{n+1}=(\color{red}{f_{k-1}}+\color{green}{f_k})f_n+(\color{green}{f_{k+1}}+\color{red}{f_k})f_{n+1}=$$

$$=f_{k-1}f_n+f_kf_{n+1}+f_kf_n+f_{k+1}f_{n+1}\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}=f_{n+(k-1)+1}+f_{k+n+1}=$$

$$=f_{n+k}+f_{n+k+1}=f_{n+k+2}\;\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

Now you do the second case with $\;n+1\;$ and fill in whatever minor details are left.

Comment: The equality is symmetric in n and k so you're actually done.

Comment: @MussuliniYes, I know...yet the details are *not there* but in justifying all the minor steps done in the above.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand it. Where did you use your Induction Hyp. ?

Comment: Exactly where it is said and shown "Ind. Hyp." for the first two summands on the left side. The next step is only doing some order and the last step is the definition of a FS.

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, answer looks good I'll just do some more reading to see if I can understand your thinking process. How do you usually approach problems with recursion like such ?

Comment: @MarcoNeves Honestly? I begin working on the proof and decide on my way, though *in this case* it is a rather special case as there are two indexes, so the choice to do induction on *their sum* looked natural.  This is mainly practice, experience...neither deep thinking nor genius involved here.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks a bunch man I'll keep practicing so I can be like you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47314/discussion-between-marco-neves-and-donantonio).

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Use induction to show that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$f_{k}f_{n}+f_{k+1}f_{n+1}=f_{n+k+1}\quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}.$$

i) Basic step. Show
$$f_{k}f_{0}+f_{k+1}f_{0+1}=f_{0+k+1}\quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}.$$

ii) Inductive step. Notice that $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$f_{n+k+1}=f_{n+k}+f_{n-1+k}=(f_{k}f_{n-1}+f_{k+1}f_n)+(f_{k}f_{n-2}+f_{k+1}f_{n-1})\\
=f_{k}(f_{n-1}+f_{n-2})+f_{k+1}(f_n+f_{n-1})
.$$